# Python is adding values to multiple instances

Tags: python

I have created a descriptor for lists.

After testing it seems that every time I append a value to a list of one instance, it is being added to another instance as well.
Even weirder, in the unittests it keeps appending to the list, and not resetting on every test.

My descriptor main class:

```
class Field(object):
    def __init__(self, type_, name, value=None, required=False):
        self.type = type_
        self.name = "_" + name
        self.required = required
        self._value = value

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return getattr(instance, self.name, self.value)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        raise AttributeError("Can't delete attribute")

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        self._value = value if value else self.type()
```

Descriptor list class:

```
class ListField(Field):
    def __init__(self, name, value_type):
        super(ListField, self).__init__(list, name, value=[])
        self.value_type = value_type

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not isinstance(value, list):
            raise TypeError("{} must be a list".format(self.name))
        setattr(instance, self.name, value)

    def __iter__(self):
        for item in self.value:
            yield item

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.value)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.value[item]

    def append(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, self.value_type):
            raise TypeError("Value is list {} must be of type {}".format(self.name, self.value_type))
        self.value.append(value)
```

Unittests:

```
# Class I created solely for testing purposes
class ListTestClass(object):
    l = ListField("l", int)


class TestListFieldClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.listobject = ListTestClass()

    def test_add(self):
        # The first number is added to the list
        self.listobject.l.append(2)

    def test_multiple_instances(self):
        # This test works just fine
        l1 = ListField("l1", int)
        l2 = ListField("l2", int)

        l1.append(1)
        l2.append(2)

        self.assertEqual(l1[0], 1)
        self.assertEqual(l2[0], 2)

    def test_add_multiple(self):
        # This test works just fine
        l1 = ListField("l1", int)
        l1.append(1)
        l1.append(2)

        self.assertEqual(l1[0], 1)
        self.assertEqual(l1[1], 2)

    def test_add_error(self):
        # This test works just fine
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            l1 = ListField("l1", int)
            l1.append("1")

    def test_overwrite_list(self):
        # This test works just fine
        l1 = ListField("l1", int)
        l1 = []

        l1.append(1)

    def test_overwrite_error(self):
        # This test works just fine
        l1 = ListTestClass()
        l1.l.append(1)

        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            l1.l = "foo"

    def test_multiple_model_instances(self):
        # I create 2 more instances of ListTestClass
        l1 = ListTestClass()
        l2 = ListTestClass()

        l1.l.append(1)
        l2.l.append(2)

        self.assertEqual(l1.l[0], 1)
        self.assertEqual(l2.l[0], 2)
```

The last test fails

```
Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/project/tests/test_fields.py", line 211, in test_multiple_model_instances
    self.assertEqual(l1.l[0], 1)
AssertionError: 2 != 1
```

When I look at the values for `l1.1` and `l2.l`, they both have a list containing `[2, 1, 2]`

What am I missing here?

I looked to the memory addresses and it seems that the lists all point to the same object.

```
class ListFieldTest(object):
    lf1 = ListField("lf1", int)


class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        l1 = ListFieldTest()
        l2 = ListFieldTest()

        l1.lf1.append(1)
        l2.lf1.append(2)

        print(l1.lf1)
        print(l2.lf1)

        print(hex(id(l1)))
        print(hex(id(l2)))
        print(hex(id(l1.lf1)))
        print(hex(id(l2.lf1)))
```

This prints

```
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
0x7f987da018d0 --> Address for l1 
0x7f987da01910 --> Address for l2
0x7f987d9c4bd8 --> Address for l1.lf1
0x7f987d9c4bd8 --> Address for l2.lf1
```

Comment: Why sometimes `self.value` and sometimes `self._value`?

Comment: @JohnZwinck self._value is only used to store the value for the value property. So _value is only used in the getter and setter of value

Comment: As far as I remember descriptor protocol, you are supposed to assign descriptor-based attributes as class variables only - otherwise, it won't work properly, see here http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/gist.github.com/ChrisBeaumont/5758381/raw/descriptor_writeup.ipynb

Answer (score 2):

`ListTestClass.l` is a class attribute, so it is shared by all instances of the class. Instead, you should create an instance attribute, eg in the `__init__` method:

```
class ListTestClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.l = ListField("l", int)
```

Similar remarks apply to `ListFieldTest`. There may be other similar problems elsewhere in your code, I haven't examined it closely.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this source](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/gist.github.com/ChrisBeaumont/5758381/raw/descriptor_writeup.ipynb), the proper form is

```
class ListTestClass(object):
    l_attrib = ListField("l", int)
    def __init__(self)
        self.l = l_attrib
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both @PM 2Ring and volcano I found the answer.

In the end this works great for value types:

```
class IntTestClass(object):
    i = IntegerField("i")
```

However for a reference type (like a list) that won't work and you have to add a new list

```
class ListTestClass(object):
    l = ListField("l", int)

    def __init__(self):
        self.l = []
```

Comment: _Everything_ in Python is a "reference type", since everything is an object, and under the hood it's manipulated via pointers, even simple integers. However, some objects (eg integers, string, tuples) are immutable, so they can be safely shared, whereas others (eg lists, dicts, sets) are mutable, and sharing those can lead to the unwanted behaviour in the code in your question. Note that in the code in this answer that `self.l` shadows the class attribute of the same name, but that class attribute can still be accessed via `ListTestClass.l`.

Comment: You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.